# Transformation from DFA to regular expression

Tags: regular-expressions

[image: dfa]

What is the correct regular expression for this DFA?

I came up with the solution

```
0|1(0(0|1))*1*
```

The problem with my solution is, that it's not possible to use the q2->q2 and then loop through q1 and q2.

The correct answer according to the paper is

```
(0|1)(1|0(0|1))∗
```

This one looks false too, because it looks like its not possible to go q1->q2->q2.

So my question is, what is the correct regular expression and why. And why is my solution may wrong (maybe more errors than I already exposed to you)?

Comment: Why don't you think the paper's answer is correct? We have a zero or a one followed by any number of either a one or a zero followed by a one or zero. That looks correct to me.

Comment: @JohnDouma Try it going from q1->q2 with 0. And then we use the q2->q2 loop once. So the word is 01. The regular expression from the paper requires one or at least three letters.

Comment: The star applies to everything after the initial character. So, for example, $0111$ which stays in state $q2$ works. This is saying that we can't have an empty string; we require an initial character. After that, we can have any number of ones or any number of zero followed by anything. Basically, everytime we get a zero after the initial one, we need another character to get us back to $q2$.

Comment: It may be clearer if you write it as $(0|1)(1|00|01)*$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the solution is fairly easy. I didn't read the answer from the paper correctly.

So `(1|0(0|1))`

is read `1 OR 0(0|1)`

Comment: You got it. You could have just said that in the comments.